# How to capture a command prompt window close event in python

Tags: python

I want to capture command window close event from Python.
In other words, when the user tries to close the command prompt window, script should detect it and display a message like `Do you really want to exit - Yes/No`

Any suggestions about how to implement this?
Please help me in doing this.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Windows?

Answer (score 4):

define like this:

```
import time

def on_exit(sig, func=None):
    print("exit handler")
    time.sleep(10)  # so you can see the message before program exits
```

- Windows:

if you install pywin32 package, you can :

```
import win32api
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)
```

- Un*x:

Or, using python internal "signal" library, if you are using under *nix system:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, on_exit)
```

Comment: I tried No. 2 but it didn't work (the exit handler was never called). I am using Python 2.7

Comment: If you are on Windows, opt for win32api