# How can a Python function be called on script exit reliably?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you register a function with all the correct handlers etc to be called when the Python script is exitted (successfully or not)?

I have tried:

```
@atexit.register
def finalise():
    '''
    Function handles program close
    '''
    print("Tidying up...")
    ...
    print("Closing")
```

...but this does not get called when the user closes the command prompt window for example (because `@atexit.register` decorated functions do not get called when the exitcode is non zero)

I am looking for a way of guaranteeing `finalise()` is called on program exit, regardless of errors.

For context, my Python program is a continually looping service program that aims to run all the time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done in pure Python. From [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html):

> Note: the functions registered via this module are not called when the
>   program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python
>   fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.

I think you may find this useful: [How to capture a command prompt window close event in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180440/how-to-capture-a-command-prompt-window-close-event-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just catch all kinds of exceptions in your main function or code block?

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately it doesn't throw an error when the user closes the command prompt, so it doesn't handle that exit. Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work

works both on `Ctrl-C` and when the assertion fails. Maybe you can use a similar construct and pack it as a decorator, or whatever.

```
def main():
  print raw_input('> ')
  # do all your stuff here  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    main()
  finally:
    print 'Bye!'
```

Comment: Okay, not sure I understand how this is to work - could you elaborate a little? Are you saying that `assert` should throw an error when the user closes the command prompt, which is then caught in the `try:...catch:` hence allowing me to handle the exit?

Comment: @James: sorry for confusion, I edited the question. `assert 0` was just an example, that it *will* catch an error and print "Bye". Also, when you press `Ctrl-C`, the `finally` part will be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid that doesn't catch the error of a user closing the command prompt running the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

> For context, my Python program is a continually looping service program that aims to run all the time.

This is very hard to get right (see [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python)). You should use a library like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/ instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
atexit.register(func)

func = lambda x: x
```

Use http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

Comment: Yup, not reliable as described above.

Comment: When user closes interpreter probably it is called os.exit() instead of sys.exit() , Correect?

Comment: Yup, quite possibly. I need to handle all exiting.