# Deleting temporary files during script evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I'm using a python package, [cdo](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Cdo%7Brbpy%7D), which heavily relies on [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html) for storing intermediate results. The created temporary files are quite large and when running bigger calculations, I've run into the problem that the `/tmp` directory got filled up and the script failed with a `disk full` error (we are talking about 10s to 100s of GB). I've found a workaround to the problem by creating a local folder, say `$HOME/tmp` and then doing

```
import tempfile
tempfile.tempdir='$HOME/tmp'
```

before importing the `cdo` module. While this works for me, it is somewhat cumbersome if I want also others to use my scripts. Therefore I was wondering, whether there would be a more elegant way to solve the problem by, e.g., telling `tmpfile` periodically to clear out all temporary files (usually this is only done once the script finishes). From my side this would be possible, because I am running a long loop, which produces one named file each iteration and all the temporary files created during that iteration would be discardable afterwards.

Comment: Just use the tempfile module discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257782/how-to-remove-file-when-program-exits It will auto-delete temp files when the file is closed.

Comment: @MeterLongCat As stated in the question, cdo uses `tempfile`, and I need to delete *before* the script finishes. Unfortunately I don't have control over the parameters that cdo passes to the `TemporaryFile()` instances upon creation.

Answer (score 2):

as the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#examples) show: you could use [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) in a context manager:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    fp.write(b'Hello world!')
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.read()
```

that way they are removed when the context exits.

...do you have that much control over how `cdo` uses tempfiles?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that control, but the example is good anyway.

Comment: ...sorry about that!